# Create proper tree like structure with TreeView control

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I've searched through this web site and others for a solution, but unfortunately everything I've tried out there have not worked.
What I'm trying to achieve is to create a tree-like structure being displayed through `TreeView` control from a `List<>`.

This is what I have so far:

```
List<string> versions = servers.Select(s => s.Version).Distinct().ToList();

foreach (var version in versions)
{
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(version);
    root.ExpandAll();
    myTreeView.Nodes.Add(root);

    foreach (var server in servers.Where(x => x.Version == version))
    {
         myTreeView.Nodes.Add(server.ServerName);
    }
}
```

What this then does, is creates the root node and child nodes in a list-type structure like:

```
VersionA
Server2
Server3
VersionB
Server1
Server4
```

But what I want to see is this:

```
VersionA
    Server2
    Server3
VersionB
    Server1
    Server4
```

Note: There will always be 2 levels in this hierarchy.
Help me please.

Comment: For clarification, `myTreeView` and `resultView` are the same?

Comment: Yes sorry, I'll correct that, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `TreeNode` has its own `Nodes` list, which is how you build the tree.  To add branches (or leaves) to the tree you need to track the current node being descended from.

In your case the code was close and can be modified by simply changing the target of the `Add` operating in the inner loop like so:

```
foreach (var server in servers.Where(x => x.Version == version))
{
     root.Nodes.Add(server.ServerName);
}
```

This will add the server nodes as leaves of the version nodes.